# Java Runtime exec Redirect On Windows

Tags: java, exec

I want to execute this command on windows, but It seems Java exec is not working with the redirect. How can I solve this problem?

```
c:/coolroid/gicater/mysqldump.exe -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -pagile -P3308 coolroid > C:/jukebackup/coolroid_1498793488965.bak
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String [] command = {"cmd" , "/C" ,cmd + " >" + finalPath};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The problem is solved.
cmd : c:/coolroid/gicater/mysqldump.exe -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -pagile -P3308 coolroid 
finalPath: C:/jukebackup/coolroid_1498793488965.bak

Thanks for your tips @ControlAltDel
Thanks @Don Peat for correcting my question.

Answer (score 0):

The piping isn't working because normally the outputstream of the application you are running would be available through Process.getInputStream().

The way to fix this is to run "cmd" first, then send in your statement via the process's OutputStream

Comment: Thanks for your tips.