# How to execute MSDOS Command from browser (PHP or Java)

Tags: java, php, windows, command-prompt

I have a USB line display, similar to the ones that are used in store point of sale systems.

To print `ABC` to this line display, I run the following command:

`echo ABC > \\.\LCLD9\`

This prints `ABC` to the line display.

I'm trying to figure out how to control this output from a website, if possible, although I am not sure if it would be possible, as I can see security issues with being able to run arbitrary commands form web pages.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838157/java-runtime-exec-redirect-on-windows

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and formatting

Comment: To confirm, you have a screen connected to the **client**, and you want to be able to change what is displayed from a web page (so each browser should only control the screen connected to the machine the browser is running on)?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out how to control this output from a website, if possible, although I am not sure if it would be possible, as I can see security issues with being able to run arbitrary commands form web pages.

This is indeed not possible on an unmodified system. There is no way for a web page to run an arbitrary command on the user's machine -- that is the *definition* of a security vulnerability.

If you can get the user to install software ahead of time, you could use a Chrome extension with the [serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial), [usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb)
 or [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) APIs to expose this functionality to web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check out function **shell_exec**. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: This works for commands on my server, but the display is connected to the local computer.

Comment: No luck there either, it is all for server side command exec.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One way is to simply have your website store the current text somewhere and then build a script on the local PC that asks your website for the current text and updates the display. You can schedule that script to run periodically using the Task Scheduler.

This script can be as simple as this (assuming PHP is installed on your local PC):

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('https://example.com/current_text.php');
shell_exec('echo "' . $text . '" > \\.\LCLD9\');
```

If you don't have PHP installed and don't want to install it, you can probably do something similar in a Powershell script or in a plain old batch file.

Note that you probably want to add some extra checks to this, you don't want to accidentally clutter your display with a 404 error page, a 500 internal server error or a network error.